# Building a package referencing a package in a parent directory in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to build a pip package from source code in a Git repository that has multiple packages that share a common package. (I am not allowed to change the structure of this Git repository.)

The structure is:

```
├── common
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── run_helpers
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── aws.py
│   │   └── s3.py
└── components
    └── redshift_unload
        ├── redshift_unload
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── run.py
        └── setup.py
```

My setup.py is as follows:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_dir={"": "."},
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": ["redshift_unload=redshift_unload.run:main"]
    }
)
```

Looking at other answers here, things I have tried so far include:

- Specifying the actual package names in the `packages=` line instead of using `find_packages()`.
- Passing `where="../../"` to `find_packages()`
- Using `find_packages() + find_packages(where="../../") in the` packages=` line.
- Everything I can think of in the `packages_dir` line.

When I run `pip install .` I get, the package installs fine, but then when I run the installed python script I get:

```
# redshift_unload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/redshift_unload", line 5, in <module>
    from redshift_unload.run import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redshift_unload/run.py", line 9, in <module>
    from common._run_helpers.aws import get_boto3_session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

What did work:

- If I moved the `common` directory to `components/redshift_unload`, then it works fine. But I can't do this. I also tried placing a symlink there in its place, but seems like that doesn't work either.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe I have found the best solution to this.

Based on this comment [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2339#issuecomment-683465763), I concluded that what I am trying to do is not intended or supported.

However, I found a workaround as follows works fine:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import rmtree, copytree

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

src_path = Path(os.environ["PWD"], "../../common")
dst_path = Path("./common")

copytree(src_path, dst_path)

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_dir={"": "."},
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": ["redshift_unload=redshift_unload.run:main"]
    }
)

rmtree(dst_path)
```

The key insight here is that, while packaging occurs in a temporary directory, the value of `os.environ["PWD"]` is available to the process, such that the common directory can be copied temporarily and then cleaned up again (using `shutil` functions `copytree` and `rmtree`) into a location that will be found by `find_packages()` before the `setup()` function is called.